# Installing Ocamlbuild

Tags: ocamlbuild, opam

I have opam version 1.2.2 and ocaml version 4.03.0. Trying `opam update -u` or `opam install mirage` gives output where the first error is:

```
[ERROR] The compilation of ocamlbuild failed at "make -f configure.make all
    OCAMLBUILD_PREFIX=/Users/josephjohnston/.opam/system
    OCAMLBUILD_BINDIR=/Users/josephjohnston/.opam/system/bin
    OCAMLBUILD_LIBDIR=/Users/josephjohnston/.opam/system/lib
    OCAML_NATIVE=true OCAML_NATIVE_TOOLS=true".
```

So I tried installing ocamlbuild directly and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I realized `make uninstall` had a license problem and followed https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-sierra-invalid-active-developer-path running `xcode-select --install` to solve the problem.

Comment: Would you know by change which specific command raises this "license problem" you are talking of? It would have been useful to see the logs of the first failed run, or maybe a rerun with `OPAM_VERBOSE=1` to get more information. If I knew which part of the Makefile rule fails for macOS users, I could display a hint in that case.

Comment: I can't retrieve the outputs I had. I actually don't know if it was a license problem. I just used that word because in the post I link to it was said to be the problem. I think the command was just [make uninstall].